# Java implementing cyclic loop

Tags: java, loops

Suppose i have digits between 1 and 5,i want to implementing simple loop between that when:

after `decrease` or `increase` new value and check that between 1 and 5(i.e. boundary conditions are cyclic, so that),

if its bigger than 5 then must be 0
if its smaller than 0 then must be 5

if its not bigger than 5 and its not smaller than 0 then value can `decrease`or `increase`.

it is looping between two number, my code seems its not correct

```
/* listCount is 5 */
/* currentPosition is 1 */

/* sample( currentPosition -- ) */
protected void sample(int position) {
    if (position < 0 && position < listCount)
        position = 5;
    else if (position >= listCount)
        position = 0;
    else
        currentPosition = position;
}
```

in this code `currentPosition --` is 0 then that must be 5 otherwise can decrease

**for more information:**

increase position until its not 6. if it is >5 then must be 0, or decrease position until its not 0. if its < 1 then must be 5

Comment: Please explain yourself better, possibly with a few examples of input/output.

Comment: @Idos simulate simple loop between two number, if currentPosition it is <0: must be 5, if its > 5 then must be 0, otherwise `currentPosition` can `decrease` or `increase`

Comment: What will change the position? Do you need boolean values whether or not the position could increase/decrease? What is the final goal?

Comment: Sounds like you need the modulus operator here!

Comment: @MariaDeleva Deleva increase `position` until its not 6. if it is >5 then must be 0, or decrease `position` until its not 0. if its < 1 then must be 5

Comment: When will the loop end?

Comment: @MariaDeleva no this loop dont finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic looks off

```
if (position < 0 && position < listCount)
```

if `position = 1` it will reset position to 5 - which does nothing.

What I think you want the function to do is:

```
protected void sample(int position) {
    if (position < 0) {
        currentPosition = 5;
    } else if (position >= listCount) {
        currentPosition = 0;
    } else {
        currentPosition = position;
    }
}
```

I would suggest increase and decrease functions separately

```
protected void increase() {
    if (currentPosition == listCount) {
        currentPosition = minValue;
    } else {
        currentPosition++;
    }
}

protected void decrease() {
    if (currentPosition == minValue) {
        currentPosition = listCount;
    } else {
        currentPosition--;
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont have zero in loop

Comment: Change 0 to a variable called `minValue` and set it equal to 1 in your case

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I understand you correctly, you want to loop continously?
Anyway, that is what I am taking away from your question about 'cyclic' ant the information in the comments. It's a good idea to split 'looping up' and 'looping down' in two different methods. to loop up, you could use this:

```
public void increaseloop(int position)
{
    if(position > 5 || position < 0){
        position = 0;
    }
    for(; position <= 5; position++){
        System.out.println(position);
        if(position == 5){
            position = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5  constantly. I am sure that if this is actually what you were looking for, you'll be able to implement the method to loop down as well.